Small Perturbation Rotation and linearization of the rotation axis
I'm reading Roger Y. TSAI and Reimar K. Lenz's paper, 'A New Technique for Fully Autonomous and Efficient 3D Robotics Hand/Eye Calibration'(IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON ROBOTICS AND AUTOMATION, 1989).
Suppose that there are two Rotation matrices, $R$ and $\Delta R$. $\Delta R$ is the small perturbation rotation matrix. $P_X$ is the rotation axis of the rotation matrix $X$, which is scaled by the rotation matrix. The paper says
$$P_{\Delta R \cdot R} = P_{\Delta R} + P_R.$$
Even if I used Rodrigues' formula and quaternion methods, I failed to explain that equation. Please give me some helps to understand why that linear approximation can be established.
Thanks in advance!
